# Android: Get app window size, including cases of split view and pop-up view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, window

I'm developing an Android app in Java using Android Studio and need to calculate the neto size of the app window (width and height, excluding the navigation and status bar).

It should be taken into account that the app can be displayed in various modes, including "normal view" (full-screen), 'split view', or 'pop-up view' (Samsung features).
How can I calculate the window size of the app considering all these display modes?

Comment: you don't have. When I developed my app I just made sure that every activity is dynamic.  which means no matter the screen or the view size it will always look they way it's intended. so example adding helpers or constraints. I tested my app on a xiaomi phone and all of the view worked just fine.

Comment: I understand the importance of dynamic design, but in my app, accurate calculations of the window height are crucial, especially when drawing content on a canvas surface in certain scenarios.

Comment: This does the trick:

Point size = new Point();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);

API level 29 and below — The size of the entire display (based on current rotation) minus system decoration areas is returned.
API level 30 and above — The size of the top running activity in the current process is returned. If the current process has no running activities, the size of the device default display, including system decoration areas, is returned.

Comment: You found a solution?. Sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

This code does the trick for me. however, it's essential to note that it hasn't been thoroughly tested across all screen scenarios and API versions:

```
Point size = new Point();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
```

> According to the API documentation:
>
> API level 29 and below — The size of the entire display (based on
> current rotation) minus system decoration areas are returned.
>
> API level 30 and above — The size of the top running activity in the
> current process is returned. If the current process has no running
> activities, the size of the device's default display, including system
> decoration areas, is returned.